Is there a way to obtain the coordinates of the position of the character and not of the bbox?
I have this code that what I do is take the characteristics of the characters from the PDF and copy them to another PDF but the problem is that the and is not the same position since I don't know why it takes the position of the bounding box (bbox) and not the character, would anyone know how to select the position and character?
This is the code :
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LTTextContainer,LTChar,LTImage,LTRect,LTLine,LTTextBox,LTFigure,LTTextLine
import fitz

text_elements= []
for page_layout in extract_pages("helve3.pdf"):
    for element in page_layout:
        if isinstance(element, LTTextBox):
            for text_line in element:
                for character in text_line:
                    if isinstance(character, LTChar):
                        print(character)
                        propiedades_texto={
                            "text":character._text,
                            "fontname": character.fontname,
                            "fontsize": character.size,
                            "x0": character.x0,
                            "y0": character.y0,
                            "x1": character.x1,
                            "y1": character.y1,
                            "matrix":character.matrix,
                            'bbbox':character.bbox
                                    }
                        text_elements.append(propiedades_texto)

        if isinstance(element, LTRect):
            print(element)
            
        if isinstance(element, LTFigure):
            print(element)
           

        if isinstance(element, LTLine):
            print(element)  
           

        if isinstance(element, LTImage):
            print(element)


print("--------------------------------------------------------")
pdf_path = "helve3.pdf"
pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_path)
page = pdf_document.load_page(0)
width = page.rect.width
height = page.rect.height
pdf_document.close

pdfNew = fitz.open()
pageNew = pdfNew.new_page(width=width, height=height) 

for text_element in text_elements:
    print(text_element)
    matrix_tuple = text_element['matrix'][-1]
    print(matrix_tuple)
    pageNew.insert_text((text_element['x0'],text_element['y1']),text_element['text'],fontsize=text_element["fontsize"],color=(0,0,0),fontname="helv")  # Inserta el texto en la posición (100, 100)
   
   
pdfNew.save("prueba.pdf")
pdfNew.close()

